# Presenting ViewController with TabBarController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, xcode8

Okay, so each time I try to present a ViewController (from the AppDelegate file's, "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" function) using the following code, my tabBar with 4 items disappears, even though the ViewController I want is shown:

```
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

    let tabBarController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "theEvents") as! ThirdViewController

    self.window?.rootViewController? = tabBarController
```

When I try the following code (also in the AppDelegate file's "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" function), then I get nothing at all:

```
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

    let tabBarController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "theEvents") as! ThirdViewController

    self.window?.rootViewController?.tabBarController?.didMove(toParentViewController: tabBarController)
```

I've tried several iterations of the two, but I still can't seem to get what I want...

Essentially, what I want is to programmatically press one of the buttons so that my third view controller becomes the first view the user sees in certain circumstances.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what exactly `ThirdViewController` is, but I'm guessing it's the view controller that's contained in the third tab of your tab controller.

The tab bar controller still needs to be the window's `rootViewController`.

If you just want to programmatically select a certain index of the tab bar controller, you can do something like this:

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tabVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabVC") as! UITabBarController  // however you defined your UITabBarController.
        tabVC.selectedIndex = 2   // or whatever you want
        window?.rootViewController = tabVC
```

And if the tab bar controller is already the root, then you could bypass the step where you instantiate it and set it to the root:

```
    if let tabVC = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
        tabVC.selectedIndex = 2
    }
```

Comment: This looks like what I want. I had that, but I didn't have the .selectedIndex, so I'm thinking that is all I was missing. I'll check it out and let you know how it goes. Thank you for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what i did for my app,
what i did was, i always navigate to the MainView and call performSegue to navigate. then i pushViewController

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem?
var mainViewController:MainViewController?
static var  handled = false

enum ShortcutIdentifier: String {
    case AddExpense
    case AddIncome
    case AddExpenseType
    case AddIncomeType

    init?(fullIdentifier: String) {
        guard let shortIdentifier = fullIdentifier.components(separatedBy: ".").last else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(rawValue: shortIdentifier)
    }


    func getUIViewController(storyboard : UIStoryboard) -> UIViewController{
        return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:self.rawValue)
    }
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    self.shortcutItem = shortcutItem
    completionHandler(handleShortcut(shortcutItem))
}


@discardableResult fileprivate func handleShortcut(_ shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem) -> Bool {

    let shortcutType = shortcutItem.type
    guard let shortcutIdentifier = ShortcutIdentifier(fullIdentifier: shortcutType) else {
        return false
    }

    return selectTabBarItemForIdentifier(shortcutIdentifier)
}

fileprivate func selectTabBarItemForIdentifier(_ identifier: ShortcutIdentifier) -> Bool {
    if AppDelegate.handled  {
        return false
    }

    var handled = false

    guard let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController else {
        return false
    }

    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1

    if let contentViewController  = tabBarController.selectedViewController?.contentViewController as? MainViewController  {
        mainViewController = contentViewController
    }else{

        guard let  navigationController = tabBarController.selectedViewController?.contentViewController.navigationController else {
            return false
        }


        print(type(of:navigationController.contentViewController))
        print(navigationController.viewControllers.count)

        let _ = navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

    }

    guard let rootView = mainViewController else {
        return false
    }

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    switch (identifier) {
    case .AddExpense:
        rootView.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Expences", sender: rootView)
        handled = true
    case .AddIncome:
        rootView.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Incomes", sender: rootView)
        handled = true
    case .AddExpenseType:
        rootView.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Expences Types", sender: rootView)
        handled = true
    case .AddIncomeType:
        rootView.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Incomes Types", sender: rootView)
        handled = true
    }

    rootView.navigationController!.pushViewController(identifier.getUIViewController(storyboard: storyboard), animated: true)
    AppDelegate.handled = handled
    return handled
}

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let theme = ThemManager.currentTheme()
    ThemManager.applyTheme(theme: theme)

    var performShortcutDelegate = true

    if let shortcutItem = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.shortcutItem] as? UIApplicationShortcutItem {

        print("Application launched via shortcut")
        self.shortcutItem = shortcutItem

        performShortcutDelegate = false
    }

    return performShortcutDelegate

}



func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    AppDelegate.handled = false
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    print("Application did become active")

    guard let shortcut = shortcutItem else { return }

    print("- Shortcut property has been set")

    handleShortcut(shortcut)
    AppDelegate.handled = true
    self.shortcutItem = nil
}
```

}